# Error to create namespace in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I had write a code in js file

```
(function ($) {
    var $r = $.loadaccess;

    jQuery.loadaccess.page.user = {
        init: function () {
            debugger;
            var k = 'dd';
            alert(k);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

var user = jQuery.loadaccess.page.user;
```

and I am calling it on .aspx page

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery.loadaccess.page.user.init();
    });
```

but it thrown error for me
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'page': object is null or undefined"

on this

```
jQuery.loadaccess.page.user = {
            init: function () {
                debugger;
                var k = 'dd';
                alert(k);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self descriptive, `jQuery.loadaccess` is null or undefined. What do you expect jQuery.loadaccess to be? You will need to create this 'namespace' yourself. For example:

```
jQuery.loadaccess = {
  page: {
    user: {
      init: function () {
          debugger;
          var k = 'dd';
          alert(k);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I wouldn't suggest adding objects to the jQuery object though, rather create your own top level namespace.

Comment: JQuery.loadaccess.page.user is my namespace

Comment: 'namespaces' in Javascript are just objects. You cannot create a property on an object if the object does not exist. Thus, if you try do `jQuery.loadacccess.something', it will error because the 'loadaccess' object does not exist. You will need to manually create all levels of your namespace (including the 'loadaccess' object). I've updated my answer.